# Why my webform with bootstrap does not look good with class form-inline in phone?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have a webform in ASP.NET with VB.NET, it's made with Bootstrap, but when i put 3 elements (a dropdownlist with selectpicker class, a textbox and a button)in class="form-inline" on PC looks good but in phone no:
[Form-inline on PC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccm1f.png)

But in phone it's look like this:
[Form-inline on Phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cR1og.png)

Here is my .aspx:

```
            <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Directorio Telefónico</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
             <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-inline col-lg-offset-3  col-sm-offset-3">
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlBuscar" CssClass="selectpicker" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="">Seleccione elemento</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="departamento">Departamento</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="ubicacion">Ubicaci&#243;n</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="extension">Num. extensi&#243;n</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="usuario">Nombre usuario</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="apellidop">Apellido p. usuario</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="apellidom">Apellido m. usuario</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="linea">Tipo de l&#237;nea</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>

                         <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
                       </span>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtBuscar" placeholder="Ingrese búsqueda" CssClass="form-control " runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" onkeypress="return EnterEvent(event)"></asp:TextBox>
                          </div>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="loading" CssClass="btn btn-default" runat="server" OnClientClick="waitingDialog.show('Procesando búsqueda, espere...', {onHide: function Carga(){ var objO = document.getElementByid('<%=loading.ClientID %>'); objO.click();}})" Text="<i aria-hidden='true' class='glyphicon glyphicon-search'></i> Buscar"></asp:LinkButton>

            </div>
             </div>
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: This is standard behaviour with bootstrap... it will display in-line if the viewport is wide enough to do this. If it is too small then it will display them horizontally. Try rotating your phone and you may find they fit in-line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read the [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline) on Bootstrap's inline form:

> Add .form-inline to your form (which doesn't have to be a ) for
>   left-aligned and inline-block controls. **This only applies to forms
>   within viewports that are at least 768px wide**.

You can add some margin to the form-controls to make them stack nicer on mobile.